# Run a scheduled task as an unprivileged user remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008, task-scheduler

I need to allow a group of unprivileged users to trigger a predefined scheduled tank on a Windows Server 2008 R2 host. I seem unable to find the respective rights to do so. Upon an attempt to connect to the remote Task Scheduler, the remote system just gives me the middle finger:
[image: You do not have permission to access this computer]

Even when a user is logged on on interactively, I cannot figure out how I would grant her the necessary permissions to run a task. In the pre-2008-era, a .job file has been created in the %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\Tasks folder, where you could manipulate ACLs and influence the task scheduler behavior. In 2008, there seems to be no similar facility.

Note that I do not want to *create* additional tasks, I just want to *run* an existing one.

Comment: It may just be me, but a scheduled task is almost by definition _not_ run on demand? Second I would expect that your users can bypass the scheduler and simply run the actual powershell, batch job or executable on demand instead?

Comment: @HBruijn at least in Windows, scheduled tasks have the option to be run on demand. It is a privilege issue - users should be able to execute a script remotely, but should not be able to read it or perform any other action on this server. Historically, scheduled tasks have proven to work well under these circumstances, although I admit that it somewhat stretches the concept of **scheduled** tasks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue under Windows Server 2012 R2 and found the following working solution:

- grant the users write access to the XML files in `c:\windows\system32\tasks`
- grant the users permissions for Powershell Remoting
- let users use Powershell Invoke-Command cmdlet to run SCHTASKS on the remote server:

```perl
powershell.exe -command "invoke-command {schtasks /run /tn TASKNAME} -computer SERVERNAME"
```